# ThreadSanitizer data race - false positive?

Tags: c, macos, thread-safety, objective-c-blocks

ThreadSanitizer is telling me I have a data race in this code, but I'm not seeing it. It seems pretty straightforward; I'm locking the mutex around all accesses to the variable. Is it actually unsafe, or is TS somehow being fooled?

```
bool AccessBool(pthread_mutex_t mutex, bool *value)
{
  bool result;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  result = *value;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  return result;
}

void SetBool(pthread_mutex_t mutex, bool *value, bool newValue)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  *value = newValue;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void WaitForQueue(dispatch_queue_t queue)
{
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;

  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

  // Some queued tasks may need to also perform tasks on the main thread, so
  // simply waiting on the queue could cause a deadlock.
  const CFRunLoopRef loop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
  __block bool keepLooping = true;

  // Loop because something else might quit the run loop.
  do {
    CFRunLoopPerformBlock(loop, kCFRunLoopCommonModes, ^{
      dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        CFRunLoopStop(loop);
        SetBool(mutex, &keepLooping, false);
      });
    });
    CFRunLoopRun();
  } while (AccessBool(mutex, &keepLooping));
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: It's the block notation used in Objective-C.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I tagged it C because it's a .c file, but if I'm using an Objective-C feature that doesn't quite work.

Comment: What is the Objective-C feature? I can't see any. And if there would be an Objective-C feature, the code in a .c file wouldn't compile unless you force the compiler to do so.

Comment: The ^{} block notation. Looks like the comment asking about it was deleted after I changed the tag.

Comment: Neither the block notation nor GCD is an Objective-C feature. It is an extension of Apple to C and it is on to be standardize in C. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)

Comment: @dbush It is stil no Objective-C feature. This is, why Apple send its wish of standardization to the WG14, which is the **----> C <----** working group. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1451.pdf

Comment: No, need for that, because it is quite clear, that an extension discussed in the WG14 is an extension the the programming language C. And it should also be quite clear, that a .c file cannot contain Objective-C features. Discussing that would be arguing … you know

Comment: I changed the code sample to the non-block version. The problem exists either way, so the block thing is just a distraction. (Well, `dispatch_async` still uses a block. Oh well.)

Comment: So this is an additional reason, that there is no Objective-C feature in the code.

Comment: Back to your real Q: Why do you deal with run loops at all?

Comment: I'm amazed this code even compiles. But the error is real. Each invocation of `SetBool` or `AccessBool` constructs a new mutex to lock since the mutex is passed by value. (What is the value of a mutex anyway?!) Pass the mutex by reference. See [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?498319-pthread-Passing-mutex-into-a-function).

Comment: Oh, yes, I would say: BINGO.

Comment: @Uncommon If this isn't C code, please don't tag it C. The correct answer to this question is very different for C, C++, and Objective-C. For example, it's definitely not "pass the mutex by reference" if this is C.

Comment: Function calling is identical in C and Objective-C. Objective-C is inherited from C. In the whole code there is nothing that is related to Objective-C. No single bit.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Right, but there *should* be -- that's what's wrong with it. A good answer would include showing not just what's wrong with this code but the right way to do what this code is trying to do, which can be different in C and Objective-C. The language tag should be the language the person asking the question is actually using.

Comment: Indeed, And the person asking **is** *using C and only C*. The code comes from a **.c** file, that means, that it is compiled as pure C. There is nothing in relation to Objective-C and if there would be anything related to Objective-C the compiler would warn. The whole code and the whole Q is completely unrelated to Objective-C. I cannot understand, why someone can think, that there is a single bit of Objective-C.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad If you think that the extension of a file is more more a clue you are wrong. I can compile a .toto file with rustc. But you do not want speak in chat so you are mono chat with yourself in comment section.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - That was the answer. I wondered why ThreadSanitizer said I had created multiple mutexes. Thanks!

Comment: And, by the way, the reason I still haven't posted an answer to this question is that I'm still not sure what language the OP is using, so I don't know which of several possible answers to give.

Comment: He is using C and only C. And I cannot see, why your answer should be different, if he is using Objective-C. Everything from C is identical in Objective-C. (Maybe except of the fact, that `id` is a reserved word in Objective-C, but not in C.)